# How to match a wildcard for strings?

Tags: string, wildcard

Please suggest a wildcard for below Firstjson list

```
Firstjson = { p10_7_8 , p10_7_2 , p10_7_3 p10_7_4}
```

I have tried **p10.7.*** wildcard for below Secondjson list, it worked. But when I tried **p10_7_*** for above Firstjson list it did not work

```
Secondjson = { p10.7.8 , p10.7.2 , p10.7.3 , p10.7.4 }
```

Comment: can you give more details? what language are you using? your examples aren't json

Comment: This looks like you are misunderstanding the syntax of regular expressions.  A regular expression of `.` matches any character and `.*` matches 0 or more characters.  so `p10.7.*` might match with `p10x7abcdefg` But `_` matches only a literal underscore.  And `p10_7_*` matches things like `p10_7_______`.

Comment: @depperm I'm doing it on groovy script and trying fetch results from json

Comment: @Wyck Okay so Can I give p10_7* so that it matches p10_7_1 etc... ? I'm new to this

Comment: Groovy's pattern matching uses a regular expression syntax, NOT a wildcard/glob syntax. So you'll have to make an appropriate regular expression.  You can search up how to convert a wildcard expression to a regular expression.  It's a bit annoying but `*` in wildcard syntax is `.*` in regular expression syntax.  Or you might be looking for something like `p10_7_\d+` where `\d` matches a digit (0-9) and `+` means to match _one or more_ of those digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use *wildcard* syntax, but Groovy expects *regular expression* syntax for its pattern matching.

#### What went wrong with your attempt:

##### Attempt #1: `p10.7.*`

A regular expression of `.` matches any single character and `.*` matches 0 or more characters.  This means:

> `p10`*{exactly one character of any kind here}*`7`*{zero or more characters of any
> kind here}*

You didn't realize it, but the `.` character in your first attempt was acting like a single-character wildcard too.  This might match with `p10x7abcdefg` for example.  It also *does* match `p10.7.8` though.  But be careful, it also matches `p10.78`, because the `.*` expression at the end of your pattern will happily match any sequence of characters, thus any and all characters following `p10.7` are accepted.

##### Attempt #2: `p10_7_*`

`_` matches only a literal underscore. But `_*` means to match zero or more **underscores**.  It does **not** mean to match characters of **any** kind.  So `p10_7_*` matches things like `p10_7_______`.  Literally:

> `p10_7`*{zero or more underscores here}*

#### What you can do instead:

You probably want a regular expression like **`p10_7_\d+`**

This will match things like `p10_7_3` or `p10_7_422`.  It works by matching the literal text `p10_7_` followed by one or more *digits* where a digit is `0` through `9`.  `\d` matches any digit, and `+` means to match *one or more* of the preceding thing.  Literally:

> `p10_7_`*{one or more digits here}*